# How to check all the column values of a corresponding value are null or not null

Tags: db2, dbeaver

So I have a table where I have column A, B, C,D. Column A has values which have corresponding multiple values in column B.I need to check if all the values in column C and D are null for the column B values.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 100 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 100 | 7 | null | null |

If you observe here. Column A has same value. Consider that a single shop. Consider Column B to be the products of a shop. Column C can be the price and Column D may be the discounts.

In the above table if I want to find out the shop which has no cost set for any product and no corresponding discount. then if I use Is Null for column C and Column D it will give me 3rd row. But I have other products from Shop 100 having cost and discounts set.

My expectations:

I want to fetch the shops for which all the cost and discount are null for all the products.

1. where all the column values are null for Column C and D,
2. all the column values are not null for Column C and D,

Comment: db2 and mysql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: Yes I have added the required one now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this (assuming it's SQL)

```
Select * from table
Where A IS NULL and B IS NULL and C IS NULL and D IS NULL;
```

And

```
Select * from table
Where A IS NOT NULL and B IS NOT NULL and C IS NOT NULL and D IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hey Hamza. I modified the asked question. Could you please go through the updated one. It will be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. where all the column values are null for Column C and D,

You can do:

```sql
select a
from t
group by a
having max(c) is null and max(d) is null;
```

> 2. all the column values are not null for Column C and D,

```sql
select a
from t
group by a
having max(case when c is null or d is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TxYqvO04).

Answer (score 0):

I tried HAVING clause. Condition - Having sum(column_name) is not null and got my answer. Thank you everyone. :)